# I had a webform Application with .net 4 Framework and downgrade to .net 2.0 Framework System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptServices not define

Tags: jquery, vb.net, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I wrote a WebForm Application with .net 4 framework everything work fine. At the time of publishing they told me that the server only supports 2.0. When I change the target framework to 2.0 I had the error:

Type 'System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService' is not defined. I have seen some other examples like here but nothing very concrete on how to fix it. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely to run into other issues as well because the web.config differs between 4.0 and 2.0 as well.

When I am forced to downgrade from 4.0 to 2.0 I usually create a new web project as 2.0 and pull in the .aspx and .aspx.cs I need from my other project's file system.

Then if I referenced anything in a .cs or .vb I can manually edit.

This assumes you weren't actually using any 4.0 features.

(create a new 2.0 project with web.config and pull everything in manually to that project from the other project)

Comment: I did made some changes like I had to change my listview for a repeater. So there is no way to change something on the configuration of the project to make it work ?

Comment: No sorry. Not that I know of. But all of that markup for your listview is retained when you copy the page etc.. Give it a shot. I just did it to verify.